# Attach bottle cage to frame w/o mount screws

Tags: frames, bottle

I'm planning on getting a bottle cage for my bike, but my bike does not have the standard mount screws for one. As I understand it, there are two types of cages: bolted cages and clamped cages. I'd prefer a bolted cage because they are cheaper ($5ish vs. $10ish).

Is it possible to drill holes directly into the frame for the bolts (I do have a good bit of experience working with aluminum)? Are there any other alternative methods for attachment, or would I be better off with the clamp cage?

Comment: I think you'll be better off with a clamp-on cage. I've never drilled holes in bicycle tubing, but jack-nuts will lock a threaded nut into the hole more permanently than just tapping threads into the walls of the tubing. (Cheap bikes have similar provisions for braze-ons, as opposed to welded-in fittings.)

Comment: I would advise a clamp-on unit.  You can buy separate clamp assemblies for bolt-on cages if you want to use a specific cage, or you can improvise with hose clamps and a strip of sheet metal.  I'd be a little leery drilling holes.

Comment: @WTHarper - There's nothing "cheap" about braze-ons.  Brazing is used on good quality steel tubing to prevent destroying the temper.

Comment: I don't think that there is any difference between bolt on cages and clamp on ones apart from the pack for the clamp on ones contains some extra bits. I have added "bolt on" cages to my bike using jubilee clips (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jubilee_Clip) around the frame slipped over the bolt on tangs. I don't know whether that brings the cost down though.

Comment: @Daniel R Hicks I was trying to say that crimp-in style nuts are the cheap alternative and was using braze-on in the generic sense of attachment points for parts and accessories. Brazed or welded fittings are totally ideal.

Comment: A water bottle cage can even be installed with a couple of the largest ZIP Ties, just pull them real tight. A strip from old inner tube can be used to increase friction or to prevent scratches from the other suggested clamp types. Also, you can install them in various places, like the seatpost, top tube, you name it. And for those not dealing with budget or theft: http://problemsolversbike.com/products/clamp_on_water_bottle_cage

Comment: Although there are many good answers here, I think I'm just going to go with a bolted cage and a clamped adapter in the end.

Comment: There's also [bottle cages](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/Models.aspx?ModelID=46011&gclid=COGkgtO2rbgCFa5DMgodJhQAEQ&utm_source=Google&utm_medium=Shopping) that mount to the seat rails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clamps are easy and reversible - causing little or no damage to tubing (metal jubilee clips might scratch paintwork, but there are plastic versions which work well)

I'm loath to drill holes in perfectly good tubing - I also would be worried about metal shavings falling to the bottom of the tube and causing problems in a bearing race.

Comment: Not to mention, this is how it is done originally, when the frame is built.

Comment: Surely at that point there is no grease etc so any shavings will be easily blown out? Also, the last two bikes I have owned have not had the bottom bearings sealed off from the rest of the tubes...which has always worried me

Comment: In my experience plastic clips do not work. I tried these at first but swapped them for metal clips after a very short while. Like, one journey.

Comment: I have two bikes (both bamboo, so that may be a factor in maintaining grip) that I use the plastic style and they work fine. They are a pain to install correctly...you have to get them on pretty tight, but once set they work well.

Comment: @JohnP - I can assure you that quite commonly the frame tubes are open to the bottom bracket.  This is desirable to allow any accumulated moisture to escape.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is possible to install a set of water bottle "braze-ons" on a frame which was not originally supplied with them.

It requires a very specific set of tools and parts.

The video below shows how a Rivnut works.

The second video wexpolains how to install a set in a bicycle frame.

Comment: +1 Nice answer, but since my main objective in getting a bolted cage was to save money, the tool needed might bake it a bit counterproductive. Helpful answer, though. Thanks

Comment: Many bike shops have the tools, and the rivnuts themselves are cheap. Also, there are many DIY versions of the tool.  They just take more time to use. See this link for example: http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/water-bottle-fittings

Comment: FYI, rivnuts can be fitted properly using two spanners and a nut and bolt that fit the internal thread.  Just takes a bit longer than using the specialised tool.

Answer (score 6):

Nylon zip ties. No tools required, no holes to drill and easily reversible.....you can even get 'em in colors.

Comment: That's not a bad idea. Have you tried this yourself? Is it a durable solution?

Comment: I wouldn't expect that zip ties would hold a bottle cage securely, unless there was at least a rubber strip between cage and tube.

Comment: Exactly @DanielRHicks, the trick is to use two or four zipties with a strip of inner tube between the tie and the bike's tube. Use the big ones, they support greater forces, and being large allows to pull them real tight.

Comment: I have indeed used these myself and I can assure you that your cage is not going to go anywhere.  A rubber strip is also a good idea as it will protect the paint finish.  May you ride on in style!

Comment: I'd still trust spiral hose clamps a lot more.

Comment: (I'm thinking of the poor job that zip ties do holding a cycle computer sensor in place.)

Answer (score 2):

Hose clamps work. Might put a piece of foam to stop the cage from rattling.

Comment: Welcome to SE - please do take a moment to browse the [tour].   Sorry - this duplicates the accepted answer posted in 2013.  Also try for a longer answer next time, with a bit more background.  A one-liner triggers an automatic flag.